# Вопрос по полиморфизму

Tags: c#, ооп

Как объекту класса kvadrat вызвать методы класса rectangle, а потом опять вызывать методы kvadrat??

```
class Rectangle
{
    public double x
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    public double y
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    public double diag
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    public virtual  double Perimetr()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("perimetr rect");
        return 2 * (x + y);
    }

    public virtual double Square()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("square rect");
        return x * y;
    }
}

class kvadrat : Rectangle
{
    public override double Square()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("square kvadrata");
        return Math.Pow(x, 2);
    }

    public override double Perimetr()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("perimetr kvadrata");
        return 4 * x;
    }
}


class MainClass
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Rectangle r = new Rectangle();
        kvadrat k = new kvadrat();

        Console.WriteLine(k.Square());
    }
}
```

Comment: `base.Perimetr()` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
class kvadrat : Rectangle
{
    public override double Square()
    {
        base.Square(); // <<======================= вот так
        Console.WriteLine("square kvadrata");
        return Math.Pow(x, 2);
    }

    public override double Perimetr()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("perimetr kvadrata");
        return 4 * x;
    }
}
```

Если надо вызывать родительские методы приведением типов, тогда вам нужна не перегрузка методов, а сокрытие. Например

```
class Rectangle
{
    public double x
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    public double y
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    public double Square()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("square rect");
        return x * y;
    }
}

class kvadrat : Rectangle
{
    public new double Square()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("square kvadrata");
        return Math.Pow(x, 2);
    }

}
```

Вызов

```
kvadrat k = new kvadrat();

Console.WriteLine(k.Square());
Console.WriteLine(((Rectangle)k).Square());
```

Вывод

```
square kvadrata
0
square rect
0
```

Comment: а по другому нельзя? приведением типов?

Comment: @Kioshilol обновил

Comment: спасибо большое